# Selecting a tab inside nav_menu toggles the dropdown

Tags: r, shiny, bootstrap-5, bslib

I have a question about `nav_menu` and `nav_select` from `bslib`.

When I try to select a tab that is nested inside a `nav_menu`, the page
navigates to the new tab, but it also opens the `nav_menu` dropdown list as it
were clicked, instead of selected from the server. Then, the dropdown does not
close until the nav menu button is clicked again. Clicking elsewhere on the page
does not toggle it.

Has anyone seen this? Is it expected behavior? Any ways around it? Thanks!

A reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(rlang)

nav_items <- function(prefix) {
  list(
    nav("a", tagList(
      paste(prefix, ": tab a content"),
      actionButton(inputId = "go_to_tab_c", label = "Go to tab C")
    )),
    nav("b", paste(prefix, ": tab b content")),
    nav_item(
      tags$a(icon("github"), "Shiny", href = "https://github.com/rstudio/shiny", target = "_blank")
    ),
    nav_spacer(),
    nav_menu(
      value = "ya",
      title = "Other links",
      align = "right",
      nav("c", paste(prefix, ": tab c content")),
      nav_item(
        tags$a(
          icon("r-project"),
          "RStudio",
          href = "https://rstudio.com",
          target = "_blank"
        )
      )
    )
  )
}

ui <- page_fluid(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  page_navbar(
    id = "main_nav",
    title = "Page",
    bg = "#0062cc",
    !!!nav_items(prefix = "page_navbar")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go_to_tab_c, {
    nav_select(id = "main_nav", selected = "c")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone arriving here, please read through this thread on the `bslib` repo about the underlying reason why this happens. In short, it's a change in `Bootstrap 5` that propagates through `bslib` and then `shiny`. The thread also includes some example code how to close the `nav_menu` using some `JS` from the `shiny` server.

Comment: The thread can be found at https://github.com/rstudio/bslib/issues/621